# Java Web Service for existing application

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am currently doing an internship where I have an existing java project that essentially processes strings and gives you an output with informations about it. I am now told to do an web interface for it, with an input field, a button to send a request, and a field for displaying the output. I was given the advice to look into REST web services. Since I have never done anything web related before, I read tons of materials, and am now a bit confused. Please tell me if I got the following points correctly.

1. For the webservice, I can use JAX-RS, so I will use a class like that:

   `@Path( "result/{input}" )
   public class ResultResource
   {
     @GET
     @Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
     public String message(@PathParam("input") String input)
     {
       return myApplication.processInput(input);
     }
   }`
2. Now I am unsure: Can I create the web interface (button, input fields) with a jsp file or a html file? So that when the button is clicked, the url "..result/input" is called and I somehow have to read the result from the page and display it in my results field.
3. To make it runnable on a server, I have to deploy my REST-servlet above on tomcat / jetty.

Would be pleased to get some answers, because I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a jsp file, you just use normal html for your form and button etc.

In your form do action="/yourServlet?param=yourInput" method="post".

And then in your servlet you can make a doPost method which will get your parameter like:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String input = request.getParameter("yourInput");
    doSomething(input);
}
```

and then do whatever you want it to. You can then send it back to the desired page with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/yourPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This should also be in your doPost. Your response here can be what you did to your input and you can then make a result field in yourPage.

To make it runnable you can indeed put in on a tomcat server.